# How do I organize/structure AngularJS logic

Tags: angularjs, architecture

Im unsure how I should structure an AngularJS app logicwise. On the serverside I do it like this:

- Request is handled by controllers
- Controllers call a service with the incoming data
- Services do database queries by calling the appropriate methods on the database layers

So on the client side I have the controllers that bind the scope to my logic, my JSON data objects and my Services.

- Do I put everything that is not related to the scope into a seperate service?
- Where do I put my data objects? Into a seperate service?
- What about two way databinding? Doesnt that write back to my JSON data objects even if I dont want that?
- How do I organize my run method? Do I group everything by resource and put it into ArticlesService.init() for instance?
- Should my services keep the JSON data objects and do all the updating on the local and remote collection (as in delete a JSON object and then call a DELETE method on the remote server?)

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad for this site, and you will probably be much better off using Google. Or you can start at the official style-guide: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html which links to https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub or you can look at angular-seed on github: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Comment: I've already looked through these guides, thats just where you put your files. Couldnt find much on Google and neither on #angularjs that's I'm asking here.

Comment: Well, between that and the Angular tutorials I doubt you'll get a better answer here. Like I said, the FAQ and Question-Asking-Help guide states that this site is for specific programming questions and your question is everything but specific. There's an example implementation for a CRUD app here: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app but you probably won't find much there that you haven't already seen.

Comment: The question is broad but it's very relevant. I faced the same problem and even if getting started with angular is easy, finding good practice and well structured code is not at all.